# CodeIgniter3 and results_array() times-out

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing a problem with making a simple query to my MySQL database using the CodeIgniter3 libraries. I am facing issues finding the bottleneck and would like to hear your opinions.

***Technical Specifications:***

- PHP 5.4
- CodeIgniter 3.1.2
- MySQL 5.1.73 (via /var/lib/mysql.sock)

**Table 'notifications':**

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| receiver_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0          |                |
| content     | varchar(254) | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| created     | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | 1000000000 |                |
| seen        | set('0','1') | NO   |     | 0          |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Direct query from within mysql:**

```
mysql> select * from notifications order by created desc limit 100;
...
...
100 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Query with CodeIgniter:**

```
//  Load User's Notifications
public function LoadNotifications($UserID)
{
    //  Load Replies
    $sql            =   "SELECT id, content, created, seen FROM notifications WHERE receiver_id=$UserID ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 100";
    $query          =   $this->db->query($sql);
    if( $query->num_rows() == 0 ) return '0';
    $results        =   $query->result_array();
    return $results;
}
```

My observations and long time of trying to find a reason revealed that this line causes the problem:

```
$results        =   $query->result_array();
```

CodeIgniter offers another way to obtain the results as an object which is by using this command instead:

```
$results        =   $query->result();
```

As you might have guessed, I am getting the same result with **PHP** eating up all CPU and NginX connection timing out with a **HTTP/1.1 504**

- I have tried to log Mysql_Slow_Queries, none were found.
- Table is using InnoDB storage engine (key buffer use ~98%)

[image: PHP CPU Usage on CodeIgniter Query]

Please let me know what you think, and where I should be looking or maybe what exactly I should be looking for. I would love to shout-out that this is a CodeIgniter bug but following the protocol, a second opinion is needed before I do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using `$this->output->enable_profiler(true)` ?

Comment: No, I am not. I have provided the code exactly as it is being used in the application. If needed, please state why, and why is a query without the profiler causing such issues. Thank you

Comment: Can you just using the query `SELECT id, content, created, seen FROM notifications LIMIT 10` and see if you have an issue? If not, that means ordering of filtering could be the issue. Try `SELECT id, content, created, seen FROM notifications ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10`. If that looks good, ordering is good. Filtering could be an issue. Try `SELECT id, content, created, seen FROM notifications WHERE receiver_id=1 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10`. If that is fine, try doing `$UserID = sprintf("%d", $UserID);` before `$sql...` to convert your UserID to an int.

Comment: Great approach @zedfoxus, descreasing the queried results to 10 brought a result, but it was unbelievably slow. Omitting the $UserID did not affect the issue, timed-out on a 100 results query and same slow results with 10 rows query. Thank you so much for your contribution.

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant enable_profiler can help you debug, it won't change anything but will print out information that might be helpful for you - see more here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/profiling.html

Comment: `seen` sounds like a boolean flag, but it is declare with 4 possible values:  "seen", "not seen", both seen and not seen, and neither seen nor not seen.  Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

It appears the problem is not on the MySQL side at all, and the evidence is that I can query any amount of rows I can in  just milliseconds.

After the `function LoadNotifications($UserID)` return the results, and while CodeIgniter was actually rendering the `$results` array returned, I had a javascript line like this:

```
foreach($results as $notification)
{
  echo $notification["content"] . "<br />";
  echo "<script> some JS code </script>";
}
```

The problem was caused by my used inline Javascript obfuscation library [CI_Minifier](https://github.com/terrylinooo/CodeIgniter-Minifier) which caused a 100 obfuscation instances to be launched simultaneously to obfuscate those 100 `<script>` lines I had inside the loop.

**Bottom-line:**

If you are using inline PHP DOM-Parsing of any type that for example can obfuscate your code or pass it to third-party software, make sure you **do not** contain that inside a look when returning results or rendering code.

The correct approach would be generating an output of whatever array you have, get out of that loop, then pipe the final output for obfuscation or whatever you are doing in a single instance.

Thank you @zedfoxus and @Dan for your attempts to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

For the first query, you need an index on `created`.  You probably need to turn that column into a numeric datatype, not `VARCHAR`.

For the second query, you need a different index, the composite `INDEX(receiver_id, created)`.  Your current `INDEX(receiver_id)` is not as good.  Since it is a prefix of the one I recommend, I recommend you remove yours.

Comment: While I do appreciate your input and comments on improving the database's performance, I'd like to mention that this is absolutely not related to my question nor does it solve the enlisted problem. Thank you

Comment: "times out" and "eating up all cpu" smack of "performance".  `result*` is waiting for the database to finish gathering the entire result set.

Comment: not really, please see my answer below. I was "in-line" obfuscating JS renturned with the result, which fired hundreds of instances of the in-line obfuscation module. The `$result` is returned in 0.01 sec no matter how marge, it was not a DB issue, thank you.